# How to add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> to the header

Tags: theming

I'm attempting to figure out a way to add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

to the header of my pages. I've heard that you could add it in your theme settings but I could not find where that would be located. I also heard you can resolve the issue using template.php in your theme. I've added

```
<?php
function retheme_alpha_0_2_preprocess_html(&$head_elements) {
    $element = array(
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array('http-equiv' => 'X-UA-Compatible', 'content' => 'IE=edge,chrome=1'),
        );
    drupal_add_html_head($element, 'chrome_frame');
}
```

to mytheme/templates/template.php

However it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Why would you use http-equiv instead of true HTTP headers? One line in htaccess or nginx config can do the trick - unless your webserver is configured not to allow it, of course. Also, see [`drupal_add_http_header`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_add_http_header/7)

Comment: Isn't preprocess_html a bit late for that? Have you tried preprocess_page instead by any chance?

Comment: You can copy html.tpl.php file into your theme and add code in this file

Comment: I switched it from preprocess_html to preprocess_page if that's what you meant. With no result

Comment: Make sure you flush all caches after adding new preprocess hooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it works for me, I just tested. I don't think you need #type and http-equiv needs to match in the html head call.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 *
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {

    $element = array(
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array(
          'http-equiv' => 'X-UA-Compatible',
          'content' => 'IE=edge,chrome=1'
        ),
      );
      drupal_add_html_head($element, 'http_equiv');

}
```

Beyond that, if it does not work, then you have some other issue. Be sure to clear all caches.